# Updating Case field based on email subject line (best practise)

Tags: visual-workflow, email2case

In this scenario, a case could be assigned to over 15 different experts listed in a multiple picklist field on the case object. With each expertise there are a number of keywords. I want to create a flow that updates a newly created case with the right expert value based on the email subject line. Each expert has around 5-10 different keywords.

I understand this can be done using decision elements and a brute force style method in flow by adding a condition for each keyword, but in this sounds messy and not ideal to maintain.

Is there a way to store the different types of expert values with their associated keywords that can then be more easily references within a record triggered flow

Comment: have you looked at custom metadata? this can be referenced by flows

Comment: Looked into this and great shout. Just not sure how best to structure it so that it can be easily reference in a flow

Comment: You'll need to use [edit] to show some examples of the mapping from subject line `->` expert